# How to map a network drive through registry under HLM

Tags: windows-registry

Based on the following registry entry I would like to map *ALL users* to a network drive.  What should be the syntax or correct location for `\\<MACHINENAME>\<SHAREDFOLDER>`

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices] 
"Z:"="\\??\\C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Shared Documents"
```

already tried followings alternatives

```
"Z:"="\\??\\<MACHINENAME>\\<SHAREDFOLDER>"
"Z:"="\\\\<MACHINENAME>\\<SHAREDFOLDER>"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Using `net use`

There's an easier to do this, no need to mess around with the Registry. Create a batch file that says:

```
net use z: \\MACHNAME\SHAREFOLDER
```

Place the batch file in the universal startup folder: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`. (Note that `ProgramData` is a hidden folder, but it's writable to Administrators.)

If you direly need to do this by adding stuff directly to the Registry, you can use the Run key. Use this `.reg` file to create an entry called `MapDrive` that invokes `net use Z: \\MACHNAME\SHAREFOLDER`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"MapDrive"="net use Z: \\\\MACHNAME\\SHAREFOLDER"
```

You could also create a scheduled task that uses the `Users` group as its user and is set to *Run only when user is logged on*.

#### With `DOS Devices`

To specify a UNC path in a `DOS Devices` entry, you need to use the special syntax `\\?\UNC\`. I don't know where the `??` (double question mark) convention came from, but it seems to be incorrect, since question marks are not escaped in paths or in `.reg` files. Therefore, to produce a network drive in this style, use this `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"Z:"="\\\\?\\UNC\\MACHNAME\\SHAREFOLDER"
```

Note that `\\\\?\\UNC\\` is literally what goes in the `.reg`; don't replace `UNC` with anything. Interestingly enough, this type of path is not valid in normal batch-style commands, but it works here and in junctions.

#### Also

Finally, there's a [Group Policy way](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902.aspx) of mapping drives if you have a Pro/Enterprise edition of Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I need to handle it through registry.

Comment: @cilerler I have updated my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate for your answer.  I already now the key you provided  but I would like to achieve this through `"Z:"="\\??\\<MACHINENAME>\\<SHAREDFOLDER>"` syntax.  I couldn't find it in anywhere what **??** stands for and how to point it to UNC paths.

Comment: @cilerler I figured it out, thanks to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx); my answer has again been updated.

Comment: `"Z:"="\\\\?\\UNC\\<host>\\<share>"` syntax didn't work. The `DOS Devices`-registry-key seems to use NT Namespace paths, so I tried `"Z:"="\\??\\UNC\\<host>\\<share>>"`. This seems to work if the share doesn't need a password (e.g. `localhost\c$`). See https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html and http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=92 about NT-Paths. (tl;dr: NT: `\??\<DosDevice>\<path>\…`; DosDevice: `C:`,`X:`,`UNC`,`COM1`,…; `\DosDevices\…`≙`\??\…`; Win32: `\\?\…`≙`\??\…`; `\\<host>\<share>\…`≙`\??\UNC\<host>\<share>\…`; `<Letter>:\…`≙`\??\<Letter>:\…`)